# Selenium Javascript unable to switch frame

Tags: selenium

I am trying to make a script in JavaScript that would involve switching frames on this particular website but I have been unable to do so. I have tried looking for the index of the frame, using the name (there's no id for the frame), using xpath, both explicit and implicit waits but to no success. It also keeps telling me an id of a frame cannot be a string, which is quite strange as normally that would work.

The same command to find the same frame on the same website works well in Python but not JS. Is anyone able to help me out?

```
driver.switchTo().frame('mainFrame');
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
const leftframe = driver.findElement(By.name ("leftFrame"));
driver.switchTo().frame(leftframe);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[11]/td[3]/a")).click();
driver.switchTo().frame("mainFrame");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare web element in `switchTo().frame` method. If you try to define a web element beforehand, most likely you will end up getting no such element exception.

```
driver.switchTo().frame('mainFrame');
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("leftFrame")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[11]/td[3]/a")).click();
driver.switchTo().frame("mainFrame");
```

Comment: I have just tried that method, but it just says that id cannot be string. I get this error
InvalidArgumentError: invalid argument: 'id' can not be string

Comment: Can I have full error stack trace  ?